# Applying callback to nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$array = array('a' => 'apple' , 'c' => 'cat', 'ar' => array('d' => 'dog', 'e' => 'elephant'));
```

**Outputting:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [c] => cat
    [ar] => Array
        (
            [d] => dog
            [e] => elephant
        )

)
```

How to I make the values of above nested array upper case while preserving the keys. I tried this:

```
function upper($str){
  return strtoupper($str);
}

$array_upper = array_map('upper', $array);
```

But it does not seem to work for nested arrays because here is the result of it:

```
Array
(
    [a] => APPLE
    [c] => CAT
    [ar] => ARRAY
)
```

Whereas I want result like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => APPLE
    [c] => CAT
    [ar] => ARRAY
        (
            [d] => DOG
            [e] => ELEPHANT
        )

)
```

Tried with `array_walk` and `array_walk_recursive` but using `print_r(...)` on return array results into `1`.

So basically how to apply a callback function to nested array that can be nested to n level. This should be easy but I am missing something :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_walk_recursive()` should work, but it modifies the array you pass in and returns a bool, which is why you get `1` printed.

Note that you need to make sure the function you pass as a callback also takes the first parameter (the array element value) as a reference and modifies that rather than returning the modified value. (unlike `array_map()`), e.g.

```
function upper(&$str){
    $str = strtoupper($str);
}
```